# Display Ubercart Attributes and Add To Cart button in separate locations on product node page?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I need to display my product page as such:

```
[-----------ATTRIBUTES-----------]
[--------BODY, IMAGE, ETC-------]
[--------BODY, IMAGE, ETC-------]
[--------BODY, IMAGE, ETC-------]
[--------BODY, IMAGE, ETC-------]
[--------BODY, IMAGE, ETC-------]

[------ADD TO CART BUTTON-----]
```

How can I split the attributes and add to cart button in that way? Is there a way to do so in a tpl file? I'd prefer to avoid absolute positioning.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new product template for your product node type.

Comment: Please try to elaborate your answer.